# error al insertar una base de datos en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estaba haciendo unas consultas en mysql y de repente me saltaba error reject 200, todo el rato. Por lo tanto decidí desistalarlo e instalarlo. Lo he hecho unas 3 veces con diferentes versiones pero en todas cuando voy a insertar una tabla me sale lo de la foto. Tengo que decir que no he puesto ninguna contraseña ni nada, los he instalado por defecto, alguien me puede ayudar?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error va como texto

Comment: @BetaM y que quieres decir con eso? que tengo que cambiar? un saludo

Comment: Que por favor edites la pregunta